# Filter multiple sheets using variable cell value

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a workbook with multiple sheets.

Every sheet with data has a common column, K, which contains Client Manager names.
In Sheet2 I have used a Data Validation field in C1 using a list, so creating a drop down where I can select a Client Manager.
So if I select Charlie Brown, and run a macro, I would like all sheets to be filtered to only show Charlie Brown’s data.

I am an absolute VBA beginner, so I have harassed Mr Google mercilessly – the majority of suggestions involve hard-coding the filter value, rather than making it a variable cell value.
The best I have found is this:

**Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()

Dim xWs As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

For Each xWs In Worksheets

xWs.Range("K").AutoFilter 1, CLng(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Value)

Next

End Sub**

When I run the macro:

•   Positive - no error!
•   Negative - nothing happens

I'm not sure what this does: **xWs.Range("K")** - the original script had a number after the column letter, but no matter what number I put after it, it makes no difference.

I also simply typed a Client Manager name into C1, with no impact. So clearly it's just all busted.
There are 8 data worksheets, plus Sheet2. The number of columns vary sheet to sheet, but none are more than AZ.

Any help would be greatly appreciated please!

Comment: “on error resume next” hides errors. Remove that line and then re run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `On Error Resume Next` hides errors, but does not deal with them. Using `Clng` definitely causes an error - this would try to convert the value in C2 to type `Long` when you're dealing with a `String`. Also, you need to specifically **not** filter Sheet2.

How about something like this? (assumes your data begins in A1 on each Sheet.)

Edited to only autofilter visible sheets.

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim clientManager As String
    Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim filterRng As Range

    clientManager = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Value

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" And ws.Visible Then
            With ws
                If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData

                lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                Set filterRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
                filterRng.AutoFilter 11, clientManager
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - works great! However, a bit of a spanner in the works sorry. It turns out the workbook I've been sent has hidden sheets - some of which are not in the same format as the unhidden sheets. As in, they only have 3 columns, for example. How do get it to ignore hidden sheets please, or at least not worry if they aren't of the same format? I deleted all the hidden sheets and the macro worked fine - however some of them are needed as there are VLOOKUP's involved.

Comment: If you want to ignore hidden sheets, change `If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then` to `If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" And ws.Visible Then`.

Comment: Thanks BB - really appreciate your help. One more thing sorry - if I want it to also ignore a sheet called "Summary" - it doesn't like `If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Or ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Visible Then`

Comment: Make that `And ws.Name <> "Summary"`, not `Or`.